# How to create a shared library for Arm linux in ELDK ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, arm

I am using ELDK ubuntu 12.04, i want to create a shared library using **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++** and use it in a project will be built and run in Arm linux (Flea box). I can create a shared library with GCC, G++ but i don't known how to create it using **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++**. I am using eclipse to create and compiler projects.
Who has experience about it may help me steps to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? Are you getting errors compiling? Linking? Running? GCC is still GCC, regardless of which code-generation backend it's been built with; if you haven't found an actual problem, then at this point you're merely asking "How can I create a shared library with GCC, given that I know how to create one with GCC?", which seems a bit silly.

Comment: @Notlikethat I want to create a shared lib by using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++, not GCC or G++. How to do that?

Comment: The only difference is that the arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ is for ARM architecture. So its usage should be similar to (not sure if the same) as G++. So you should be able to generate the shared library as you usually did.

Comment: "gcc/g++" is just the native-targeted version for whatever system you're running on - if the idea of changing the name of a command is so intimidating, perhaps try with x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ first ;)